# How to use \SetSinglespace from setspace?

Tags: line-spacing, setspace

The file [`setspace.sty`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/setspace) documents the command `\SetSinglespace`:

> ```
> % GT:  Tue 10 Dec 1996:  Instead of fixing singlespacing to exact unity,
> % allow user to redefine it (only slightly, please!) from its initial
> % value of unity, in the case when a particular font is slightly larger
> % or slightly smaller than its point size would indicate.  This change
> % affects setspace's single spacing commands, and LaTeX's footnote and
> % float environments.  The one and a half, double, and arbitrary
> % spacing commands are unaltered.
> ```

which is followed by

> ```
> \newcommand{\SetSinglespace}[1]{%
>   \def\setspace@singlespace{#1}%
> }
>
> % Here's the default single line spacing value.
> \SetSinglespace{1}
> ```

I was under the impression that I could use `\SetSinglespace` to change the behavior of “single spacing”. When using [Fira Sans](https://ctan.org/pkg/fira) in my documents, I want to use the font’s recommended leading, which is [1.4 times the font size](https://github.com/mozilla/Fira/issues/67). I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\SetSinglespace{1.167}% 1.4/1.2
%\setstretch{1.167}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

But it had no effect.

Note that `\setstretch{1.167}` is *not* a solution, as it turns off line stretching in footnotes and floats. In my case the line stretching is desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have set the skip for use when `\singlespacing` is active. However, you never make this active.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\SetSinglespace{1.167}% 1.4/1.2
\singlespacing

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: spacier Fira]

Comment: I stumbled across the same solution seconds after I posted my question. :) However, this seems to me like a flawed design of `setspace`: 1) `\SetSinglespace{1.167}` actually semi-activates line stretching, since floats and footnotes *are* stretched without issuing `\singlespacing`. 2) There is no `\ExecuteOptions` to set up default option `singlespacing`. 3) Even there is a default option, the package uses `\AtEndOfPackage`, but isn’t `\AtBeginDocument` better? I’m curious to hear your thoughts on this. And if you agree, then I suppose I should contact the author.

Comment: Ehhh, `setspace` also forgets to update `\footnotesep` via `\footnotesep\setspace@singlespace\footnotesep`, which causes the separation between footnotes unmatched with the stretched line spacing. I guess the author(s) didn’t foresee that someone would actually change `\setspace@singlespace` from unity.

Comment: @RuixiZhang Then changes you made in the preamble would get changed when you do `\begin{document}` which probably isn't what you want. I'm not certain about the footnote separation. There's going to be an issue here, isn't there, about what the correct behaviour is exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Just `\SetSingleSpacing{<whatever>}` has no immediate effect, because of

```
\newcommand{\SetSinglespace}[1]{%
  \def\setspace@singlespace{#1}%
}
```

and no `\singlespacing` declaration afterwards. The fact you get right spacing in footnotes is because `setspace` actually *adds* `\singlespacing` when footnotes are typeset.

Calling `\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}` would be of no use, since you do `\SetSingleSpacing` after the package has been loaded.

Why does the package use `\AtEndOfPackage` instead of `\AtBeginDocument`? Because the settings for the interline spaces are done after `setspace` has been loaded and with `\AtBeginDocument` the user's settings would be overwritten.

Anyway, you *don't* need `setspace` for this. Just

```
\linespread{1.167}
```

in the preamble will do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\linespread{1.167}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\[
x+y=z
\]
abc\footnote{\lipsum*[4]} \lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The output for

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetSinglespace{1.167}% 1.4/1.2
\singlespacing

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\[
x+y=z
\]
abc\footnote{\lipsum*[4]} \lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

is the same.